# Looping of string in C programming

Tags: c, string

I am now doing an assignment about cookies ordering system and there is a "Order Number" there. I would like to display my Order Number in this format "TARC 000XX". So how can I type in this format? And since it's a ordering system, so I want to loop this Order Number (each customer will have different order number - 1st customer is TARC 00001, 2nd customer is TARC 00002 and etc.) 
So how can I loop this too to let the order number keeps changing if the next customer wants to make ordering?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question, and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site.

Comment: The easiest way is to create a number and increment for each customers, then convert it to string and concatenate it with "TARC "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
int order_number = 1;
printf("TARC %05d\n", order_number);
order_number++;
```

and it will format the string to print out like "TARC 00001" then "TARC 00002", etc.

**EDIT:** In the context of a loop it might look something like this

```
for (int order_num = 1; order_num <= max_num_orders; order_num++) {
    printf("TARC %05d\n", order_num);

    /* Do other stuff with current order if needed */
}
```

Comment: I have tried it and it works. But may I know how to loop the statements? (In order to let the order number keeps changing)

Comment: @StevenThoo I added an edit for it might be used inside a loop, there are other ways to do it but this seemed the most straight forward

Comment: Thanks @tbejos! I would like to ask if I want to generate a membership card number for customers who apply for a membership, how can I do it? Is there any straightforward and easier way to do it? (The membership card number should be in 7 digits).

Comment: @StevenThoo you may be interested in learning about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form, since you are probably building a database. The key, in this case, of the customer table would be the customer id, and of the order table, the TARC number.

Comment: @Neil Edelman I would like to have the coding and I think the one you sent me might not be useful for me. Anyway still thanks for your info!